# Bootstrap Modal Iframe Joomla

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I am currently Trying to alter **[this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-media/video-channels/16316)** component to use bootstrap modal instead of its own, for the light box used by the component is not responsive at all.. and this component is built... very much in a weird way...

But i have got the key files for what i need to do, I just am not sure where i am going wrong.

Here's the variable that is the link for the modal:

```
$link = '<a class="youModal" data-toggle="modal" href="'.JURI::base().'index.php?option=com_jusertube&amp;view=lightbox&amp;rid='.$video['id'].'&amp;'.$yorvuser .'='.$youtubeuser.$doautoplay.'&amp;eh='.$eheight.'&amp;ew='.$ewidth.'&amp;st='.$showtitle.'&amp;height='.$popupy.'&amp;width='.$popupx.'" data-target="#youModal">';
```

and then the JS that activates the modal:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    srztb_init('a.youModal');//pass where to apply srzthickbox
    imgLoader = new Image();// preload image
    imgLoader.src = srztb_pathToImage;
});

function srztb_init(domChunk){
    jQuery(domChunk).click(function(){
    var t = this.title || this.name || null;
    var a = this.href || this.alt;
    var g = this.rel || false;
    srztb_show(t,a,g);
    this.blur();
    return false;
    });
}

function srztb_show(caption, url, imageGroup) {//function called when the user clicks on a srzthickbox link
        jQuery('#youModal').removeData("modal");
        jQuery('#youModal').modal({remote: jQuery(this).attr(url)});
}
```

and then the biggest chunck of the code where the iframe is generated:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package         JUserTube 
 * @version         5.6.0
 *
 * @author          Md. Afzal Hossain <afzal.csedu@gmail.com>
 * @link            http://www.srizon.com
 * @copyright       Copyright 2012 Md. Afzal Hossain All Rights Reserved
 * @license         http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPL
 */

// No direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

/**
 * Content categories view.
 *
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_weblinks
 * @since 1.5
 */
class JusertubeViewLightbox extends JViewLegacy
{

    function display()
    {
        $filepath = dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../modules/mod_jusertube/'.'savedxml'.'/';
        if(!isset($_GET['yuser'])) $_GET['yuser'] = 0;
        if(!isset($_GET['auto'])) $_GET['auto'] = 0;
        $rid = $_GET['rid'];
        $auto = $_GET['auto'];
        if(isset($_GET['ttv'])) $ttv = $_GET['ttv'];
        else $ttv = 0;
        if($_GET['yuser']){
            $youtubeuser = $_GET['yuser'];
            $filename = $filepath.'youtube_'.$youtubeuser.'.xml';
        }
        else{
            $youtubeuser = $_GET['vuser'];
            $filename = $filepath.'vimeo_'.$youtubeuser.'.xml';
        }
        if($auto == 1){
            $autotext = '&amp;autoplay=1';
        }
        else{
            $autotext = '&amp;autoplay=0';
        }
        if(is_file($filename)){
            $data = file_get_contents($filename);
        }
        $rss = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
        $videos = array();
        $u =& JURI::getInstance();
        $url = $u->toString();
        $url = str_replace("view=lightbox","view=video",$url);
        $p2 = strpos($url,'&auto=');
        $url = substr($url,0,$p2);
        $url.='&auto=1&eh=385&ew=640&st=yes';
        $url = str_replace('&','&amp;',$url);
        if($_GET['yuser']){
            foreach($rss->channel->item as $item){
                $guid_split = parse_url($item->link);
                parse_str($guid_split['query'],$temp_v);
                $tid = $temp_v['v'];

                if($tid == $rid)
                {
                    $videos['title'] = (string) $item->title;
                    $videos['embed'] = '<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="'.$_GET['ew'].'" height="'.$_GET['eh'].'" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$tid.'?fs=1&amp;rel=0'.$autotext.'" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
                    if($GLOBALS['pageprotocol']=='https'){
                        $videos['embed'] = str_replace('http:','https:',$videos['embed']);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            foreach($rss->channel->item as $item){
                $tlnk = $item->link;
                if($ttv == 1){
                    $pos1 = strpos($tlnk,'com');
                    $tid = substr($tlnk,$pos1+4);
                }
                else{
                //$pos1 = strpos($tlnk,'#');
                $pos1 = strrpos($tlnk,'/');
                $tid = substr($tlnk,$pos1+1);
                }
                if($tid == $rid)
                {
                    str_replace('&amp;','',$autotext);
                    $videos['title'] = (string) $item->title;
                    $videos['embed'] = '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'.$tid.'?'.$autotext.'" width="'.$_GET['ew'].'" height="'.$_GET['eh'].'" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>';
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
?>
<div id="youModal" class="modal hide fade flex-video" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h2><?php echo $videos['title']?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php echo $videos['embed'];?>
            </div>
</div>
<?php
        exit();
    }

}
?>
```

Sorry I know the last part has a lot of code, and the messy-ness of the code is due to me altering the components code, I would really like to avoid re-writing the entire component just for a modal window.

Any Help Greatly Appreciated..

Comment: the perfect example of "use a framework to do less work that ends up in doing much more work". Not your fault, anyway. I feel you, bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than add in all the javascript yourself how about using the modal and renderModal function in the JHtml class

Source code: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/cms/html/bootstrap.php#L262

Render modal function is beneath that

Comment: brilliant thanks.. excuse the stupidity but, what would i write exactly?